# wordpress sidebar moves on tablets (atleast ipad)

Tags: wordpress, tablet, sidebar

My first webpage (http://strandservice.fi). A modified twentyeleven theme in WP (i know, should have created a childtheme).

My problem is that the sidebar moves down on phones and ipads, I understund that it does it on phones, but not why it does it on ipads. The sidebar seems to be working fine on computers when run on 1024 × 768, which is ipad2 resolution (it even works fine on 800 x 600). It is also working fine on ipad emulators I have used to test it.

Is there any somewhat easy solution to this? Can I force the page to keep the sidebar where it should be untill it reaches some min-resolution set by me?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Does the main wrapper div have a fixed width? Does the sidebar? If everything has a fixed width then the sidebar should stay in place and show a scrollbar instead, when the content is too wide for the screen.

Comment: they are not fixed so that they will scale for different resolutions, can I use something like @media is_ipad() to set fixed width only for ipads?

Comment: But it doesn't make much sense if you're having this problem that the fluid layout is getting all over the place... I usually use, with the iPad, the same CSS rules I use for desktop... You should check then your min-width rules, the problem may be there...

Comment: yeah, but I did not find any min-width in the css other than something for comments, and those are disabled

Comment: Yep, the problem is the way the CSS reacts when the screen goes to 800px and less, do you have a way to disable that one? The @media (max-width: 800px) rules

Comment: YES! It seems to be working now, found a plugin (mobble) that lets me identify tablets and phones (in this case is_ipad()) added "and !is_ipad()" to every @media and now it behaves as it should. Ofc i would prefear to identify tablets without plugins but that can wait for later.

edit: should i post this as an answer to my own question?

Comment: I'm glad you solved it. Congrats!